# Symfony - add boolean action field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I disabled delete action button for my user list entity and now I am trying  to set my 'enabled' boolean field from my entity instead of it.

I tried something like:

```
entities:
    User:
        class: AppBundle\Base\Entity\User
        controller: AppBundle\Controller\UserController
        disabled_actions: ['delete']
        list:
            fields: ['id', 'email', 'fullName',]
            actions:
                fields: ['enabled', type: boolean]
```

When I put it in list -> fields it works fine like boolean but actions -> fields always throws an error.

Comment: You forgot to say which error you are getting. Can you also clarify your last sentence?